# Prevent users from accessing a url directly Yii 2

Tags: php, html, yii2

I have this piece of code that if the user clicks on it the link will be replaced by text making it unable to be clicked again. The problem now is that if the user access it directly in the url so it will simulate a link click. So how do I prevent users from accessing urls directly?

```
<?php 
$isAdded = ActiveSubject::find()->where(['clientid' => $_user,'subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid'],])->exists();
if($isAdded):
?>
<b><p class="text-muted">ADDED</p></b>
<?php else: ?>
<p>
<?= Html::a('<b>ADD</b>',['site/addsubject',    'subjectid'=>$subjects['subjectid'], 'clientid' => $_user],['class' => 'btn-info btn-transparent btn-large']) ?>
</p> 
<?php endif; ?>
</td>
<td>
<?= $subjects['slots'] ?>
</td>
 <td>
<?php if($isAdded): ?>
<p class="text-primary">Awaiting Confirmation</p>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-filters.html.. You have to use filter concept for this..

Comment: How do I apply it though in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['addsubject'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['addsubject', 'yourmodelname'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'managerModule1', 'managerApp'],
                ],   
            ],
        ],         
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                    'addsubject' => ['post'],
                ],
        ],

    ];
}
```

checkout this 2 answers also

[how to deny the access of url in yii even if we know the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489316/how-to-deny-the-access-of-url-in-yii-even-if-we-know-the-url)

[how to limit access url view on yii2 by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661844/how-to-limit-access-url-view-on-yii2-by-id)

In which you can understand the use of filters.

Comment: what if there is already code in the behaviors function? I am using the SiteController.php by the way?

Comment: i am not damn sure but then also we can use matchCallback method,

Step : 6 

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/771/rbac-super-simple-with-admin-and-user/

Comment: What I mean is in the rules array the sitecontroller has already an action `['logout']` so am i allowed to add add another action `['addsubject']` in the rules array?

Comment: yes ofcourse you can .. seee the step : 6 they used about action as well..

Comment: Oh ok I saw your post I get it now.

Comment: to be frankly i have never faced this kind of problem so i am not 100% sure... But your way looks ok... Try once.. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121585/discussion-between-vijay-nathji-and-quinlanlent).

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/771/rbac-super-simple-with-admin-and-user/  take a look on step : 6

Comment: Thanks you are very helpful. The solution is to make another array so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a POST link so that it has to clicked and can't be directly run from the browser

ie.

adding `'data-method' => 'post'` to `HTML::a`

```
<?= Html::a('<b>ADD</b>',['site/addsubject',    'subjectid'=>$subjects['subjectid'], 'clientid' => $_user],['class' => 'btn-info btn-transparent btn-large', 'data-method' => 'post']) ?>
```

And in the Access Rules you can add rule to only accept POST Request

i.e

```
'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'addsubject' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Edit:
Below is sample for `SiteController`

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => True,
                        'actions' => [],
                        'roles' => []
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'captcha'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                    'addsubject' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: You need to add this to the behavior function of your controller. Updated Answer

Comment: @Unknown : He is is using SiteController.php.. so how can he modify the behavior function which doesn't affect other actions?? May be matchCallback or Callback can be used... but i also want to learn how can we do this.

Comment: @Quinlanlent : put this in your public function behaviors()  or modify exixsting public function behaviors()..  in your SiteController.php