# Stop user to switch from URL

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `Yii2`. My main URL is `http://ip/backend/web/`. Whenever a user opens this link he will be redirected towards a home page

[image]

But if a user changes the URL from `http://ip/backend/web/` to `http://ip/backend/` the below screen will be shown

[image]

I want all users not to access it. Like if anyone hit the `http://ip/backend/` it will not allow any user to see that page

I searched for the solution and found out the following link [Prevent users from accessing a url directly Yii 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092234/prevent-users-from-accessing-a-url-directly-yii-2) but still, I am unable to perform the task

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to add these lines in to your `.htaccess` file (located in project root directory)?
```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Comment: just create an empty `index.html` in `/backend/` folder

Answer (score 2):

create a `.htaccess`  file at **backend folder** in your project.

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ web/$1
```

or `Options -Indexes`

**But this is not perfect**

You have to do this through the root of the project. And configure access to the `frontend` and `backend` folders. And prevent indexing all folders and files.

create a `.htaccess`  file at **root folder** in your project.

For content depending on your project and folders, get help through the links below

 [Link 1](https://www.saiyanweb.com/blog/5-htaccess-for-yii2-advanced-template) , [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525320/enable-clean-url-in-yii2/), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118691/yii2-htaccess-how-to-hide-frontend-web-and-backend-web-completely) , [link 4](https://gist.github.com/ptflp/8706c0fbd697e93e486b2df024f2ea47)

**create a .htaccess file manually in Windows:**

start **Notepad** and then File->Save As. And Write .htaccess and choose "All Files" as the type.  Save at the end.